# HasConversion() and foreign key relationship with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to extend the [AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity) library. One part of that is a creation and modification info on users and roles:

```
public class CustomIdentityUser<TKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    // public virtual TKey Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public virtual TKey CreatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey? ModifierId { get; set; }
}
```

[`IdentityUser<TKey>`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs) is the original identity model which has the `TKey Id` property. `CreatorId` and `ModifierId` reference the `Id`, the latter can be `null` if there was no modification yet.

The following examples use `int` for `TKey`.

**Nullable `TKey` problem**

The first problem I ran into was making the `ModifierId` nullable. `TKey?` does not work. EF Core migration always generates code that sets it to **not** nullable:

```
ModifierId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
```

If there is solution to this in the first place, I'd be very thankful! I tried it with a `where TKey : notnull, IEquatable<TKey>` constraint on `CustomIdentityUser<TKey>` with no luck ([NRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/embracing-nullable-reference-types/) is enabled).

```
public class CustomIdentityUser<TKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : notnull, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey? ModifierId { get; set; }
    // or
    // [AllowNull]
    // public virtual TKey ModifierId { get; set; }
}
```

When i set the property to not required in the `DbContext` like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>().Property(u => u.ModifierId).IsRequired(false);
```

I get this exception:

> The property 'CustomIdentityUser.ModifierId' cannot be marked as
> nullable/optional because the type of the property is 'int' which is
> not a nullable type. Any property can be marked as
> non-nullable/required, but only properties of nullable types can be
> marked as nullable/optional.

As far as I understand the concept of nullable reference types this would only work with reference types like `string` but not with value types like `int`. I need both.

---

I ended up creating a struct to hold the `TKey`

```
public readonly struct NullableKey<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public NullableKey(TKey id) => Id = id;

    public TKey Id { get; }

    public static implicit operator TKey(NullableKey<TKey> key) => key.Id;
    public static implicit operator NullableKey<TKey>(TKey key) => new(key);
}
```

and changed my `CustomIdentityUser<TKey>` model to

```
public class CustomIdentityUser<TKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey CreatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual NullableKey<TKey>? ModifierId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I set it up in the `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // also tried ValueConverter<NullableKey<TKey>?, TKey> with no luck
    var nullableKeyToTKeyConverter = new ValueConverter<NullableKey<TKey>, TKey>(
        v => v.Id,
        v => new NullableKey<TKey>(v)
    );

    modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
    {
        b.Property(u => u.ModifierId).HasConversion(nullableKeyToTKeyConverter);
        // b.HasOne<TUser>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.ModifierId); // => no good
    }
}
```

If I run `Add-Migration` with the relationship code (last line) commented out, the result is as expected:

```
ModifierId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
```

After adding the relation manually

```
table.ForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Users_Users_ModifierId",
    column: x => x.ModifierId,
    principalTable: "Users",
    principalColumn: "Id");
```

and `Update-Database` the app runs perfectly fine including foreign key constraint checks.

**EF Core foreign key problem**

As soon as I add the relationship code directly to the `DbContext` (`b.HasOne<TUser>().WithMany()...`), the migration and also running the app fails and I get the exception

> The relationship from 'ApplicationUser' to 'ApplicationUser' with foreign key properties {'ModifierId' : NullableKey<int>?} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : int} because it is not compatible.
> Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Where `ApplicationUser` inherits from `CustomIdentityUser<int>`. What I find funny is that the message quite literally describes my `HasConversion()` implementation while saying, it's not compatible.

So, what am I missing?

**Using navigation properties**

Based on [Panagiotis Kanavos' comment](https://#comment135487326_76853793) I tried using a navigation property instead of the foreign key:

```
public class CustomIdentityUser<TKey> : IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual CustomIdentityUser<TKey>? Modifier { get; set; }
}
```

This works. But my target is to create a library which later is used by several apps. They should be able to implement a `ApplicationUser` inheriting from `CustomIdentityUser<TKey>` with the preferred type for `TKey`. As soon as I do that, I get the exception

> A key cannot be configured on 'ApplicationUser' because it is a
> derived type. The key must be configured on the root type
> 'CustomIdentityUser'. If you did not intend for
> 'CustomIdentityUser' to be included in the model, ensure that it
> is not referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a
> configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on
> a type that is included in the model.

I guess, I could extend to `CustomIdentityUser<TKey, TUser>` and having the navigation property of that type, but this seems quite crazy. Additionally I personally find it not attractive to only having a navigation property which requires an additional database query for lazy loading or bloating the query for a single user otherwise when I only wanted to know the `ModifierId`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why create your own `NullableKey` that mimics `TKey?` instead of adding a nullable `ApplicationUser` property? Eg `ApplicationUser Creator` and `ApplicationUser? Modifier` ?

Comment: Is adding the target type instead of the foreign key the usual practice? I never tried that, but now that you say it, I can imagine it to work. I'll give it a try, thanks! But anyhow: Is this best practice? I always saw a navigation property (which ApplicationUser would be technically) as optional.

Comment: Yes, in fact that's why ORMs exist in the first place. ORMs like NHibernate and EF Core are trying to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not database tables. Instead of IDs and FK values, they load graphs of objects where related objects appear as properties, not IDs. In the EF Core [Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) example, the Blog class has a Posts category full of Post objects, and Post has a Blog property. FK properties are used for convenience and can even be omitted.

Comment: @IvanStoev the comments didn't move the focus. `NullableKey` isn't needed and only adds problems. It seems it was created because *migrations* didn't handle `TKey?` correctly. The solution to this is to either fix the generated migration or not use migrations. I think there's a way to customize migration generation but frankly, I rarely use them

Comment: I already tried the `notnull` constraint with no luck.
@PanagiotisKanavos I tried your approach and it basically works. But this comes with other problems. I updated my question. Is there no solution for the foreign key problem. I mean, am I doing something wrong or is it EF Core. And no, it sadly isn't only migration. Even with already correctly setup database, EF core throws this exception when running the app.